# GPIO number vs Pin number. Which to use?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I am writing a code for an ultrasonic distance sensor. The code worked fine when i used the gpio numbering system for the wires connecting to the gpios and sensor. As soon as i connected the sensor to the car for which i have been using pin number for the motors then the sensor stops working. When i change the gpio number of the sensors to the pin number then it works fine again. Can anybody explain it to me why is that happening?
[image: This picture shows Pin numbers as well as gpio numbers]

Comment: We can't really answer without seeing your code. However you will presumably be constantly switching between pin numbering modes which is likely to cause problems.

Comment: so, you originally wrote the code using GPIO numbers, and then `connected the sensor to the car for which i have been using pin number` ... well as you can see, the GPIO number and pin number are different ... so, if your code uses GPIO3, that's not the same as your *car* pin3 - clearly, once you've changed your code to use PIN3, that will correspond to the PIN3 of the car (I'm using 3 as an example only of course, since you've shown absolutely nothing about YOUR code, just a generic picture of a pi that provides no information about your problem)